# Why does C# Configuration System fail to Initialize when run as a CGI by IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, cgi, app-config, application-pool

I have a C# executable that is intended to be run as a CGI.

It does not behave the same when invoked from the command line as when invoked as a CGI.

The code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

class Foo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //throw new Exception( "POINT-A: Seen through browser and at command line" );
        var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        throw new Exception("POINT-B:");
    }
}
```

When I run it from the command line, I get this (it is expected):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: POINT-B:
   at Foo.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\brian\My 
Stuff\MMG\Development\mra_query\src\simple.cs:line 10
```

When I browse to it as a CGI, I get this (this is unexpected):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String dir, Boolean normalize)
   at System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at Foo.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\brian\My Stuff\MMG\Development\mra_query\src\simple.cs:line 9
```

Why is "POINT-B" reached when invoked from the command line, but something goes wrong when invoked as a CGI?

I have an App.config file, and it resides in the same folder as the EXE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>  
    <startup>   
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />  
    </startup>  
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="Setting1" value="May 5, 2014"/>  
    <add key="Setting2" value="May 6, 2014"/>  
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

Does this config file need to be put in some special place for IIS to use it?  Does the IIS ApplicationPool play some part in this that I am not considering?

The exception mentions "Illegal characters in path" but I struggle to understand its meaning.  It seems to be checking for permissions to read the configuration file.  That file is at the path shown below.  Is that one space in the path a problem?

```
C:\Users\brian\My Stuff\MMG\Development\mra_query\cgiroot
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never run any CGI from IIS.  However, IIS may set your app to run in an IIS _virtual directory_ rather than in a physical path, and that path information may not be something the config system likes.  Log information from your app somewhere that includes the `Main` routine's `args` parameter and stuff from System.Environment.  You may find something.

Comment: Since you are one of maybe couple people tried running C# code as CGI directly (and "couple" is high end estimate) you should prepare for long journey... I'd recommend to debug the code and see exact path causing the exception. As first step I'd would get rid of spaces from the path (also I suspect code is getting Uri instead of the file path).

Comment: I am considering dumping the CGI implementation in favor of ASP.NET.
..back to the books for me...